# Using Meteor.wrapAsync for complex nested functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have been playing around with the below for a while and I am really struggling to get my head around `wrapAsync` in meteor.

My general use is that I am using `zerorpc` to call a function running on a python server and pass some arguments which are user generated in a meteor app.

My understanding is that I must create a function which takes an argument and a callback:

```
function f1(arg, cb) {
  console.log('i am f1', arg)
  zClient.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:4242');
  zClient.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('RPC client error: ', error);
  });
  zClient.invoke('hello', arg, (err, res, more) => {
    if (err) { console.error(err); }
    else { console.log('Update: ', res); }
    if (!more) { console.log('Done'); }
  });
}
```

Here is my callback:

```
function cb(error, result) {
  if (error) console.log('cb error: ', error);
  console.log('here is the cb: ', result);
}
```

And finally the meteor method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'model.train'(arg) {
    console.log('method invoked: model.train', Date.now())
    let wf1 = Meteor.wrapAsync(f1);
    console.log(wf1(arg))
  },
});
```

So I think my issue is that inside my wrapped function I have yet another async function which when I attempt to wrap that I am getting a :

```
Exception while invoking method 'model.train' TypeError: Cowardly refusing to pack object with circular reference
```

Also there must be a better way as reading that code becomes a real pain!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not think you could make `.on('error', ...)` run synchronously, because it is an event listener and may get fired many times. Only the `invoke` command  could run synchronously and should be used in `model.train` method.